# Convert String to numbers separated by dots where a=1 and z=26

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I would like to convert string to integers as below, separated by "."
with `a=1`,`b=2`,...`z=26` 
`text = 'Hello World"`

Expected output:

```
     H.E.L .L. O  W. O. R. L. D
---> 8.5.12.12.15 23.15.18.12.4
```

```
#split the words
text ="Hello world"
text = text.upper()
splitted_text = text.split(" ")

#map characters to integers
import string
for x, y in zip(range(1, 27), string.ascii_lowercase):
    print(x, y)
```

I don't know how to proceed from here..

Comment: So... split the string into words, map each letter in the word to an integer, join the integers with `.` characters? Have you tried something like that?

Comment: please provide clear inputs and outputs for your question. Also explain what have you tried so far and what didn't work.
There's no visible correlation between your input and output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "Hello World".lower()
li = []
for i in text:
    if i!=' ':
        li.append(str(ord(i)-96))
    
print('.'.join(li))
```

This should work